# How to use @@if statement inside @@for of gulp-file-include?

Tags: html, gulp

I am using gulp-file-include to pre-compile html pages.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include

Here is my sample code.

```
@@for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
  <div class="foo">
    @@if (`+i+` == 0) {
      Hello
    }
    <p>`+foo[i]+`</p>
  </div>
}
```

The `@@for` loop and `` <p>`+foo[i]+`</p> `` work as expected.

However, I could not get the `@@if` statement inside the `@@for` loop work correctly. I want to check if i equals to 0.

If I change `` @@if (`+i+` == 0) `` to `` @@if (`+i == 0+`) ``, the `@@if` statement is always true.

If I change `` @@if (`+i+` == 0) `` to `@@if (i == 0)`, the `gulp-file-include` even does not compile. It says, 'i is not defined'.

Could anyone help me to figure out this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the order of parsing in the library. First it parses `if` and sees just text instead of variables. If you swap `if` and `for` parsers in `index.js` file of `gulp-file-include` you should be able to use this:

```
@@if (`+i+` == 0)
```